# how to display all the options of a html5 datalist element when there is no text in the input box?

Tags: javascript, html, html-datalist

I want to display all the options available within the datalist element when length of the text input equals 0. I have tried firing a down arrow keypress event but somehow that gets overridden every time.
I had read somewhere that , on focus of the input, on down key arrow press, the dropdown reveals all the options. Was trying to mimic that behaviour through this code
This is the input box to which the options get appended dynamically:

```
<input class="chosen-select-zone-start-end grey-placeholder" onkeyup="showHint(event, this.value)" id="start-zone-flowInput" list='start-zone-list' placeholder="Select Start Zone"  autocomplete="on" />

function clickevent(){                

         var e = $.Event("keydown");
         e.which = 40;
         e.keyCode = 40;
         console.log("evetn", e);
         $("#start-zone-flowInput").focus().trigger(e);     
         // $("#start-zone-flowInput")
         e.preventDefault();
    }

function showHint(event, val) {
        console.log(val, val.length);
        if(val.length === 0) {
            console.log("firing event .....");
            clickevent();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Share your code here

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: Added code as an edit

Answer (score 0):

You can "display" the option values when the input gets the focus like in this snippet. (From your code it looks like you just want to log each one.)

As alternatives to the `focusin` event, you could run the function on the `input` event -- or if you want to run it on each keystroke, `keyup` worked fine for me too (eg: `if(event.code == "ArrowRight")` -- but as you discovered, an exception exists for `ArrowDown` and `ArrowUp`, which have default behavior (in Chrome, anyway) that I could not prevent with `event.preventDefault()`.

```js
const options = document.querySelectorAll("#start-zone-list > option");
document.addEventListener("focusin", logOptions);

function logOptions(event){
  if(event.target.id == "start-zone-flowInput" && event.target.value == ""){
    for(let option of options){
      console.log(option.innerHTML);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input class="chosen-select-zone-start-end grey-placeholder" id="start-zone-flowInput" list='start-zone-list' placeholder="Select Start Zone"  autocomplete="on" />
<datalist id="start-zone-list">
  <option>a</option>
  <option>b</option>
</datalist>
```

Comment: I think I explained the problem a little incorrectly. the logging was for test. I want the dropdownlist to show all the options when there is no text in the box. i had read somewhere that , on focus of the input, on down key arrow press, the dropdown reveals all the options. Was trying to mimic that behaviour through this code

Comment: That happens automatically for me in the latest Chrome. When I run the snippet, the options appear below the input (or above it if there is no screen space below). Using ArrowUp or ArrowDown highlights options from the list, allowing me to select the highlighted option with Tab or Space. (That's the "default behavior" I mentioned.) Do you see different behavior? What browser version are you using?